# Having trouble registering a call to jest function

Tags: node.js, jestjs, discord, discord.js, ts-jest

I am trying to get check that `interaction.update()` has been called using `expec(buttonInteraction.update).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`.
It works if I remove the supabase line, or if I take the `await` away from the supabase line,
but not with supabase
even though I've mocked supabase, and even though logging 'after' works
I tried attaching `then(() => console.log('done'))` and it does log 'done'. I tried putting a console.log() after `interaction.update()` and it also works.

```js
console.log('userid', userId)
await supabase.from('todos').update({ reminder: reminderTime }).match({ message_id: messageId }).contains('pinner_ids', [userId])
console.log('after')
interaction.update()
```

Comment: Can you share what code you have in your test

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out, I needed to use await before expect in my test function.